# Nodejs error code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'

Tags: node.js

Here is the code. I am trying to post a login request for authentication to mongodb server using postman. The error is:
[error in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAhBF.png)

My code is:

```
router.post("/login", async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({username:req.body.username})
        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong username");


        const hashed = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, process.env.USER_PASS)
        const password = hashed.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        password !==req.body.password && res.status(401).json("Wrong password");
        res.status(200).json(user);
    }catch(err){
         return res.status(500).json(err)
            
        
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: You are calling `json` two times. Calling `.json` doesn't automatically return from a function

Answer (score 0):

When you do the password check you send a 401 response, but the code flow continues and then you try to send the 200 response although you have already sent a response.

Make sure you only send one response, for example (but there are many ways do it):

```js
return password !== req.body.password
  ? res.status(401).json("Wrong password")
  : res.status(200).json(user);
```